# Prove that $\log(A \otimes B) = \log(A \otimes I) + \log(I \otimes B) = \log(A) \otimes I + I \otimes \log(B)$

Tags: logarithms, tensor-products

How do you prove the following identity for matrices $A$, $B$ and identity matrix $I$? The $\log$ here is for matrices and not elementwise.

$$
\log(A \otimes B) = \log(A \otimes I) + \log(I \otimes B) = \log(A) \otimes I + I \otimes \log(B)
$$

I know that

$$
A \otimes B = (A \otimes I) \times (I \otimes B)
$$
but how does it work in the proof of the identity above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean that $A\otimes B=(A\otimes I)\cdot (I\otimes B)$, rather than the sum?

Comment: What are $A,B$? (Matrices?) What is the definition of $\log$ here? (The usual infinite sum does not converge everywhere.) The questions needs more context, I guess.

Comment: My mistakes, thanks Paul and Martin. I've updated the question.